# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'width' of undefined, javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, asp-classic

To start off with, I have drop downs that I'm trying to expand to fit a user-related search (say: Billy Bob's Restaurant - 98765) with this (this is written in classic ASP):

`Response.Write "<td id='aRow' onMouseOver=""resizeMenu(" & i-1 & ", " & numOpts & ")"" colspan=2 style='padding-left:5px;'>" & vbcrlf`

I then have a function that's throwing the error: **Cannot set property 'width' of undefined.**

This is the function here:

```
function resizeMenu(theOpt, numOpts) {

var i, thisOpt;
var toAdjust;   

if (numOpts > 1 ) {
    toAdjust = 60 / (numOpts - 1);
} else {
    toAdjust = 0;
}

for (i=0; i < numOpts; i++) {
    thisOpt = document.getElementById("anOpt" + (i+1));
    if (i == theOpt) {
        if (numOpts > 1) {
            document.getElementById('aRow')[i].width = (optWidth + 60).toString() + "px";
            thisOpt.style.width = (optWidth + 40).toString() + "px";
        } else {
            document.getElementById('aRow').width = (optWidth).toString() + "px";
            thisOpt.style.width = (optWidth - 20).toString() + "px";
        }
    } else {
        if (numOpts > 1) {
            document.getElementById('aRow')[i].width = (optWidth - toAdjust).toString() + "px";
        } else {
            document.getElementById('aRow').width = (optWidth - toAdjust).toString() + "px";
        }
        thisOpt.style.width = (optWidth - toAdjust - 20).toString() + "px";
    }

}
```

};

When I hover over the drop down menus, I get the error. I've looked through the code, and I haven't been able to figure out exactly what's wrong.

I should also note that I've inherited this code and I'm fairly new to programming in JavaScript. The error shows up in Chrome's debugger. In Firefox and IE11 it's not showing up in the debugger. If I comment out the section beneath the last curly brace before my for loop, the script only error messages once the page is finished loading.

Comment: Having multiple elements on the page with the same id is a bad practice.

Comment: I'll get to looking at that as well. This code is approximately 9 yrs old, I'm trying to get it functional for current time. Thanks for the pointer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
   document.getElementById('aRow')[i].width = (optWidth + 60).toString() + "px";
```

That code expects `.getElementById()` to return a NodeList when the id is used by more than one element on the page. Browsers *used to* do that, but as far as I can tell both Firefox and Chrome don't.

Using the same id for multiple elements is contrary to the purpose of an identifier. You can get your code to work in browsers that support `.querySelectorAll()` by changing code like that to

```
   document.querySelectorAll('#aRow')[i] // ... whatever ...
```

Oh, and in general an error like "Cannot [do something] property "something" of undefined" means that you've got code like

```
      x.something
```

but `x` is `undefined`; in other words, the code has expectations that aren't being satisfied, so it fails with that error.  Therefore to track down the source of such errors, you just have to look through the code for places where the property name is used after a `.` or inside square brackets.

Comment: Thanks for the code to get it to work in Chrome and Firefox! I'm finding it doesn't work in IE11, however.

Thanks, also, for the extra information - very helpful!

Comment: @slimsea well personally I think it would be OK for all browsers to return a list of just one item for `querySelectorAll('#something')` so maybe that's what IE is doing. The best thing to do would be to repair that bad page design you've been given, but I understand that that might be a mess.

Comment: That'll be my project after I can get the functionality back. Once that's rolling, I'll be dealing with the rest of the design - it's a bear and a half. Thanks for all your help!